# Best practices for field names in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, naming-conventions

I'm looking at simple ways of defining, in Java, some lightweight service and data access layers on top of ElasticSearch. My POJO data objects will naturally have property names in camelCase, but I'm wondering if I should use camelCase for the field names in the ElasticSearch type mappings. In the data repository world, and in particular in traditional RDBMS, field names are definitely not camel cased. If I'm not mistaken, there seems to be a trend in the NoSql world to use underscores in field names, e.g. first_name. Is this a common practice for ElasticSearch ?
If so, does this mean I have to configure a Jackson based conversion service that is able to map back and forth between the camelCase and underscored field names ?

Answer (score 6):

Just do what is best for your application. Having a mapping service introduces overhead that will slow things down, especially with large amounts of data. I'm using it primarily with JavaScript applications and I use camelCase.

Comment: If I use underscores in the index/type field names, I will have to map back and forth between the camelCase Java properties and the underscore-based ElasticSearch field names, there's no way around it. Annotation-based frameworks like Jackson should make that relatively painless, hopefully.

Comment: Yes, IF you use underscores you would. So just don't use underscores. Like I said, do what's best for the application. With elasticsearch there are no conventions or best practices with naming. Use the conventions that work best for your app. ES is built to handle large amounts of data very quickly. Adding a mapping layer goes against this purpose since it slows everything down.